# How to compare the data between two models that have the same tables name in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Assume you have 2 databases scripts (*Source* & *Destination*) with the same structure and different data.

This is the *source* database:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psVbVdJz7PbH2KXkqw1S3CkIviynIba8/view?usp=sharing

And this is the *destination* database:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvyFqpQ_meEXOyYmoUKuZHfINEFfAN--/view?usp=sharing

1. Load data from Source Database
2. Compare the data from source database to the destination database.
3. Depending on the comparison show result in one of four groups:

   - Data already exist with no change.
   - New data ready to be moved.
   - Data to be updated.
   - Data to be deleted
4. Then I can deploy the changes to the destination Database.

Can anyone help me to solve this task?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: start an MVC project and added two models and can't know from where i would start...

Comment: start by being able to fetch the data you want to compare - good luck!

Comment: because the table's names in the 2 models are same , they conflicted when added . what i should do ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1:

1. Introduce inert, delete update triggers for SOURCE DB tables

   - Save changes in Log table(new table)
2. Create stored procedure to read log table and update destination DB
3. Call this new SP in schedule time via SQL jobs

#### Method 2:

1. Replicate source db in order to sync changes to destination.

Comment: First of all, i have a problem with adding source and destination because both of them have the name of tables ...

Comment: How can i make method 2 ?

Comment: Refer this microsoft tutorial [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-2017)